# Creating pdfs in Python with Pisa / xhtml2pdf

Tags: python, pdf, pisa, xhtml2pdf

I know there are a lot of questions based on pdf creation in Python but I haven't seen anything based on creating pdfs with Pisa or xhtml2pdf.

Here is my code.

```
pisa.pisaDocument(cStringIO.StringIO(a).encode('utf-8'),file('mypdf.pdf','wb'))
```

and then

```
pisa.startViewer('mypdf.pdf')
```

I assembled this over a couple different tutorials and examples but every single thing that I've tried always results in the pdf being corrupted and I get this message when trying to open the pdf.

"Adobe Reader could not open 'awesomer.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)."

This message occurs even when I don't use the .encode('utf-8') on the string.

What am I doing wrong? Does the encoding on my Mac have to do with this?

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest closing the file manually, had a simmilar problem. Try this:

```
f = file('mypdf.pdf', 'wb')
pisa.pisaDocument(cStringIO.StringIO(a).encode('utf-8'),f)
f.close()
```

Comment: better approach because close() the file is important

Comment: And that's why using `with` is awesome ;)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing the following:

```
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(cStringIO.StringIO(a).encode('utf-8'),file('mypdf.pdf','wb'))
if pdf.err:
     print "*** %d ERRORS OCCURED" % pdf.err
```

And then see what the error output is.

I'm not sure what string you are encoding but this might also help:

```
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(cStringIO.StringIO(html.encode(a)).encode('utf-8'),file('mypdf.pdf','wb'))
```

It depends on if `a` needs to be html encoded

Comment: Weirdly, if I try `os.system("xhtml2pdf %s" % (filename))` it will work from the commandline but not trying from Python itself, what do you imagine is going wrong here with the encoding?